# MSBUILD .NET 7 Path Linux in Makefile

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core, msbuild, mono

I want to use MSBUILD from .NET 7 directly in Makefile and not the old mono version with MSBUILD 15.0

Old Path from Mono

```
MSBUILD_PATH=$(MONO_DIR)/msbuild/15.0/bin
```

New one in .NET 7?

Mono MSBUILD Github

https://github.com/mono/msbuild

DOTNET MSBUILD Github

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: There is no separate binary, so simply use `dotnet msbuild`.

Comment: @LexLi There **is** a separate binary that is cross-platform but there is no installer for MSBuild alone.

Comment: @MakiWolf, @LexLi is correct about using `dotnet msbuild`. MSBuild is embedded in the `dotnet` tool and the `msbuild` subcommand accepts the switches and argument, same as the standalone version. In command lines you can replace `msbuild` with `dotnet msbuild` for .NET 7.0.

Comment: The mono/msbuild repo is out of date. The dotnet/msbuild is the source for current versions of MSBuild (both standalone and embedded in the `dotnet` tool).

Comment: Does someone know if mono msbuild is active development and will recive an update

Comment: Because I have seen that there is an open PullRequest with update to MSBUILD 17.0 which is not merged and commented in https://github.com/mono/msbuild/pull/435